# does using many choose step effect the performance of the query gremlin Or How is a Choose step executed in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

i have a simple favourite query which tells if an item is favourite to a person

```
g.V().has('personId','3f857b1').choose(identity().out('favourite').has('itemId','48a680b'),constant('Already_favourite'),choose(V().has('itemId','48a680b'),constant('NotFavourite'),constant('InvalidItem')))
```

is it a bad practice to write nested choose steps as it is in other programming languages

i wanted to know if we could implement stored procedures in gremlin

Comment: i personally feel that choose follows if else or switch implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it a bad practice to write nested choose steps

No, but I would still write your query differently. Don't waste compute time and stop the traversal quickly, if the item doesn't exist. On the other hand, if it exists, try to find it by its id; don't fetch the `itemId` property for every adjacent vertex:

```
result = g.V().has('itemId', '48a680b').as('item').
           V().has('personId','3f857b1').coalesce(
                 out('favourite').where(eq('item')).constant('Already_favourite'),
                 constant('NotFavourite')).tryNext().orElse('InvalidItem');
```

Comment: thank you  daniel this explanation was  very helpful